# What is causing these huge gaps?

Tags: css

I am trying to display several items from a query onto this page. I am trying to make them so that 6 images are on a line and evenly spaced. However, it seems that no matter how I change the css, I still keep ending up with huge gaps in some places.

[image: Screenshot]

Here is the code I used to create this section:

```
    <div class="container2">
    <div class="category"><h2>All Items</h2></div>
        <div class="display">
          <?php do { ?>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="details.php?recordID=<?php echo $row_Master['Master_ID']; ?>"><img class="thumb" src="img/<?php echo $row_Master['Img']; ?>"/>
                <br />
                <?php echo $row_Master['Name']; ?></a></li>
            </ul>
            <?php } while ($row_Master = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Master)); ?>
          <!-- end .display --></div>
          <?php
        mysqli_free_result($Master);
        ?>
<!-- end .container2 --></div>
```

and the CSS associated with it:

```
.container2 {
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width:95%;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
 }

.display{
    width:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.display ul li {
    float:left;
    max-width:15.67%;
    margin: 0 0 8% 1%;}

.display ul{
    list-style:none;
    }

img.thumb {
    border:0;
    max-height:150px;
    min-width:16.67%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding:3px;}
```

Can anyone help me remove these huge gaps, plz?

Comment: You'd need to clear the float on the element that's sticking out. Or try a different approach like flexbox or grid.

Comment: yeah this is like a poster child for a flexbox use case.

Comment: Flexbox did help some, the large gabs are gone. However, I still need to get it down to 6 in a row and even though the images are all exactly the same size, I can't seem to make the rows even up.

Here is my new css:

    .display{
 clear:both;
 display:flex;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
 padding: 0 4px;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: space-around;
 overflow:hidden;
    }

    .display ul li {
 flex: 14.29%;
 min-width:14.29%;
 padding: 0 4px;}

    .display ul{
 list-style:none;
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox for the win.

You can get six across wrapping rows with this config. The flex container gets:

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

And the flex items get:

```
flex: 0 0 16.666%;
```

I added several comments in the CSS to explain what I did here. This approach takes a bit of practice but once you get it you will never use floats for layout again.

Here is a great resource that explains the flexbox approach really well: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.display {
  border: 2px solid red; /* just for demo visibility */
}

.display ul {
  /* ul reset */
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  
  /* flexbox layout - flex container config */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.display ul li {
  border: 2px solid dodgerblue; /* just for demo visibility */
  padding: 10px; /* use padding to create spacing between items, remove the borders to get the final look */
  
  /* flex item config */
  flex: 0 0 16.66%; /* 100 divided by 6 is 16.666... */
}

.display ul li span {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.display ul li img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container2">
  <div class="category">
    <h2>All Items</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="display">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="x">
          <img class="thumb" src="https://picsum.photos/120" />
          <span class="name">Thing 1</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="x">
          <img class="thumb" src="https://picsum.photos/120" />
          <span class="name">Thing 2</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="x">
          <img class="thumb" src="https://picsum.photos/120" />
          <span class="name">Thing 3</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="x">
          <img class="thumb" src="https://picsum.photos/120" />
          <span class="name">Thing 4</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="x">
          <img class="thumb" src="https://picsum.photos/120" />
          <span class="name">Thing 5</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="x">
          <img class="thumb" src="https://picsum.photos/120" />
          <span class="name">Thing 6</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="x">
          <img class="thumb" src="https://picsum.photos/120" />
          <span class="name">Thing 7</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="x">
          <img class="thumb" src="https://picsum.photos/120" />
          <span class="name">Thing 8</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="x">
          <img class="thumb" src="https://picsum.photos/120" />
          <span class="name">Thing 9</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="x">
          <img class="thumb" src="https://picsum.photos/120" />
          <span class="name">Thing 10</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when I tried this on my page, it put all the images in a single column on the left. I even tried taking it to a new page with just the normal php info and the body tags. I used your css to style it on a brand new style sheet.

When I moved the flexbox layout into the .display section, it started to do better. However, only some of them have 6 on a line. All of my images are exactly 190px X 190px, so I don't understand why it is messing up unless it is the text causing it.

Comment: I tried setting the text to max width same as the ul li and that didn't change the layout at all except the words were stacked under the image on the left.

Comment: There should be one source of truth for the width, the `li` elements. Everything inside should just flow be filling that width. Is your text in `span` elements like in my answer?

Comment: Yes, I had it exactly like you had it.

Comment: use border on the `li` elements so you can see exactly what they are doing. If you see any `li` that is wider than 1/6th then inspect the elements inside that. Both the image and the text need CSS rules to ensure they do not expand beyond the intended width. Also double check the the `flex` rule on the `li`s as well as any other other CSS applying to them that could override the width.

Comment: The images are the right size, but the text is pushing further than the image.

Comment: I put it on a temp page if you want to see it. You can find it at https://fv2cheats.rainbow-solutions.tech/1.php. That way you can see what it looks like.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. With a little more tweaking on the css, I finally have it the way I want it.

Comment: Here is what I used:

* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.display {
  /* flexbox layout - flex container config */
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: center;
 text-align:center;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.display ul {
  /* ul reset */
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.display ul li {
  padding: 10px; /* use padding to create spacing between items, remove the borders to get the final look */
  /* flex item config */
  flex:16.67%; /* 100 divided by 6 is 16.666... */
}

.name {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  max-width:150px;
}

Comment: After adding the header and containers back to it, I had to add a class to the image and make it also max out at 150px.